Move cursor to end of line in RStudio
When I press the keyboard shortcut ⌘ + right arrow in RStudio on a Mac, the cursor move to the end of the line (see left hand arrow in attached).
What keyboard shortcut can I use to move the cursor to the end of code (see right hand arrow in attached).
See screenshot attached for what I mean by 'end of code'.

